# Adding hundreds of Images to pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

How can I add hundreds of Images(with their actual size that is with out any scale down/compression) to PDF using itextsharp. I want to add these in certain tabular format with fixes no of images per pdf page. All the images are of same size.
How can I do it?

Comment: I am on initial phase of this module so don't have much code, scenario is that I have hundreds of png imgaes in my computer's directory. I traverse that direcrtory and got all the images in that directory and I need to add these images to pdf in tabular format having fixed number of images per pdf page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code to add image in a pdf

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 30, 30);
MemoryStream PDFData = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, PDFData);
doc.Open();

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.WidthPercentage = 100F;

Image imgLogo = Image.GetInstance(<image_path>);
PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell { BorderWidth = 0F,  Padding = 3 };
cell1.AddElement(imgLogo);
table.AddCell(cell1);

//Add your more images.

doc.Add(table );
doc.Close();

writer.Close();
```

Comment: HI I am working on WCF service. I want same functionality.I tried above code but it gives me error and this my code                    Image imgCheckBoxChecked = Image.GetInstance("suc.png"); I get following  error Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\suc.png'.